# Is there a jackson annotation to suppress unnecessary wrapping of JSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson

The class I'm serializing:

```
public class LogsDTO {

    /** The logs. */
    private List<LogDTO> logs;

    /** Meta data. */
    private Meta meta = new Meta();

    // more
}
```

And the generated JSON:

```
{"LogsDTO":{"logs":[{"id":11,"archived":false}],"meta":{"totalPages":0}}}
```

I'd like my JSON to look like:

```
{"logs":[{"id":11,"archived":false}],"meta":{"totalPages":0}}
```

Is there a way to annotate so that this happens?

Thanks

Comment: The correct standard behaviour for Jackson is the way you want it. Are you configuring a custom ObjectMapper?

Comment: @Leon Yeah the objectMapper is configured to wrap it, but I'm wondering if there was an annotation to override that at all?

Comment: Try using @JsonRootName and set the value to an empty string

Comment: I tried that now, it does not work.

Comment: Alternatively you should be able to construct an `ObjectWriter` from `ObjectMapper` (writer = mapper.writer()), then configure that without root name (`writer = writer.withRootName("")). I think the problem with annotation is that empty String means "just use the class name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@JsonRootName`: class annotation used to indicate name of "wrapper" entry used for root value, if root-wrapping is enabled.

Says in jackson docs : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations

Related Jira Task: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-630 1.9 and above versions supports it.

When investigate the [source code of @JsonRootName](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/blob/d6b439abe2c2f6ad8a3398a52ac1cb65c047593d/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.java),

They commented alwaysWrap method.

> /*
>    * Optional marker property that can be defined as `true` to force
>        * wrapping of root element, regardless of whether globally
>        * "root wrapping" is enabled or not.
>        *
>
> * Note that value of `false` is taken to mean "use defaults",
>        * and will not block use of wrapper if use is indicated by global features.
>        *
>        * @since 2.4
>       public boolean alwaysWrap() default false;
>        */

They have a plan to activate it on v2.5

> As of 2.4, one missing feature is property "alwaysWrap", which is hoped  * to be added in 2.5, and would be used to force root name wrapping  * for individual types.

Comment: The OP wants the wrapper completely removed

Comment: Leon, improved my answer, you can check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Map of type `Map<String, Object>`. This not really nice solution uses no Annotation. I just want to show other possibility how to do avoid json wrapping:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    List<LogDTO> logs = new ArrayList<LogDTO>();
    logs.add(new LogDTO(1, true));
    logs.add(new LogDTO(2, false));
    logs.add(new LogDTO(3, true));

    map.put("logs", logs);
    map.put("meta", new Meta(33));

    Gson gson   = new GsonBuilder().create();
    String json = gson.toJson(map);
    LogsDTO dto = gson.fromJson(json, LogsDTO.class);

    System.out.println(json);
    System.out.println(dto);

}
```

produces:

```
{
    "meta":{
       "id":33
    },
    "logs":[
       {
          "id":1,
          "archived":true
       },
       {
          "id":2,
          "archived":false
       },
       {
          "id":3,
          "archived":true
       }
    ]
 }
```

and

```
LogsDTO [logs=[Log [id=1, archived=true], Log [id=2, archived=false], Log [id=3, archived=true]], meta=Meta [id=33]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a custom serializer,turning off global wrapping off, and turning on wrapping per class. It seems that even when you turn global wrapping off, Jackson adds wrapping for list elements of a class that has wrapping.
One difference from your code is that for me the list was wrapped by its own class.
It was something like this:

```
    @JsonTypeName("interface") 
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)  // wrapping per class instead of global in the mapper
    public class InterfaceDTO
    {        
        private InterfaceIpListDTO interfaceIpListDTO; // The list property for which I want to turn off wrapping

        @JsonSerialize(using = com.tufin.securetrack.integration.rest.facade.serializer.InterfaceIPListWithoutWrapperNameSerializer.class)  // Gonen
        public InterfaceIpListDTO getInterfaceIpListDTO() {
            return interfaceIpListDTO;
        }
}

public class InterfaceIPListWithoutWrapperNameSerializer extends JsonSerializer<InterfaceIpListDTO>{
    @Override
    public void serialize(InterfaceIpListDTO interfaceIpListDTO, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();
        for (InterfaceIpDTO interfaceIpDTO : interfaceIpListDTO.getInterfaceIpDTOs()) {
            jsonGenerator.writeObject(interfaceIpDTO);
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
    }    
}
```